# How do I convert probability standard error to log odds standard error?

Tags: probability, meta-analysis, effect-size

I am conducting a meta-analysis of individual studies that report probabilities and their standard error as an effect size. I plan to convert the probabilities and standard errors to the natural logarithm of the odds, however, I am not sure how to convert the standard errors of the probabilities into SEs of the natural logarithm of the odds.

Is there a formula to convert these? Better yet, is there a way to do this in R-studio?

Comment: mayne this helps:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158481/how-to-convert-the-standard-error-of-the-log-odds-ratio-to-the-odds-ratio-standa

Answer (score 0):

Best to convert SE to n given that SE²=pq/n
Then run a meta-analysis of np (cases) and n using [MetaXL](https://www.epigear.com/index_files/metaxl.html) using the Freeman-Tukey transformed proportion. Also see these papers:
[FTT paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/jebm.12445) and [JECH paper](https://jech.bmj.com/content/67/11/974)